# valor do input apagando no click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, input

Eu tenho esse código em `javascript` que passo valores para `inputs`. Quando utilizo esse código ele insere os dados no `input` normalmente mas quando eu faço um `click` depois de ter passado os valores o `input` apaga automaticamente o valor que foi inserido. Seu eu substituir `this.getAttribute('data-email')` por uma `string` por exemplo: `user_email = "abc"` o valor é passado para o meu `input` mas não é apagado quando faço `click`. como faço para passar o valor de forma que ele não seja apagado?

```
$('.userEdit').click(function() {
  var user_email = this.getAttribute('data-email');
  var user_type = this.getAttribute('data-type');
  var user_function = this.getAttribute('data-function');

  function myFunc(elem, val) {
    return document.getElementById(elem).value = val;
  }
  myFunc("edit_form_user_email", user_email);


});
```

Comment: Como o botão (ou elemento) que tem a classe `userEdit` está definido?

Comment: **<a class="btn btn-warning btn-xs userEdit" data-toggle="modal" href="#" data-target="#userEdit"
                                                                                   data-email="<?php echo $user_f->users_email;?>"
                                                                                   data-type="<?php echo $user_f->fk_user_type; ?>"
                                                                                   data-function="<?php echo $user_f->fk_user_function; ?>"**

Comment: Você tem um problema com o código PHP que está gerando esta página, não com o JavaScript. Dá uma olhada no código fonte da página no *browser* para ver o valor que está sendo preenchido no campo `data-email`. Você pode também comparar com http://jsfiddle.net/orfge35a/, que mostra que o seu código funciona bem, contanto que o HTML do .userEdit esteja correto.

Comment: Está tudo correto com o PHP- Se eu der um alert(user_email) ele me retorna o email perfeitamente que peguei no data-email com php

Comment: Tente depurar o código no JavaScript, e compare-o com o jsfiddle que eu enviei, para ver qual a diferença. Ou adicione mais detalhes à sua pergunta para que possamos entender melhor o que está acontecendo.

Comment: Eu substitui na tag a <a> o **" data-email="<?php echo $user_f->users_email;?>"** por **data-email="abc"** e ele me retornou no input esse valor "abc", mas quando clico dentro ou fora do input esse valor automaticamente some. Se eu não utilizar no codigo javascript o getAttribute() o erro deixa de ocorrer e os valores não são mais apagados, mas preciso do getAttribute() para conseguir recuperar os valores que pretendo dentro do meu elemento <a>

Comment: Poste o seu html para podermos lhe ajudar melhor, pelo que estou vendo, se você possui a class userEdit em todos os seus inputs, ao clicar em um deles apagará o valor do email